# Mirroring iMac through Apple TV

Tags: imac, airplay

iMac (mid 2011) Mac OS X (V 10.7.5) 2nd generation Apple TV - Airplay icon not appearing and not appearing in settings. No security software running. Any tips?

Comment: The intricacies of Apple OSs - now see it apparently needs to be 10.8 and that 10.7.5 isn't good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You have met all requirements except Mac OSX. Airplay requires OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.0 or above).